# The constructor JSONArray(Object) is undefined in android

Tags: android, json, arrays

I am facing the problem to getting jsonarray from Jsonarray(object). error at this line 
**jsonArray = new JSONArray(value);** error "The constructor JSONArray(Object) is undefined"

```
public static JSONArray getPropertyJsonArray(GraphObject graphObject, String property) {
    if (graphObject == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Object value = graphObject.getProperty(property);
    if (value == null || value.equals(EMPTY)) {
        return null;
    }

    JSONArray jsonArray;
    try {

    //error line
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(value);



        return jsonArray;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        try {
            return (JSONArray) value;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not `JSONArray(GraphObject)` constructor. What you can do is to retrieve the `JSONObject` that represent the `GraphObject`

```
JSONObject jsonObj = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
```

From the documentation

> getInnerJSONObject() Gets the underlying JSONObject representation of
>   this graph object.

**Edit**

As pointed out by **@Weston**, with the latest api (19), the constructor that takes as parameter an [Object](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.Object)) has been added. If you want to use it you have to compile with the kitkat's sdk

Comment: i am integrating Facebook sdk in my android application. and this single line stopping me to go ahead in my project.

Comment: But there is a constructor that takes an `Object`: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.Object) I'd expect a runtime exception maybe, but not compile time error.

Comment: @weston, thanks to point it out. I didn't know about that. It was added with the latest api (19), hence the op is compiling against an older verion

Comment: Ah yes, just spotted that's API 19 myself.